# Why std::sort actually moves the content of std::string?

Tags: c++, sorting, std, std-ranges

What is the specific reason that both `std::sort` and `std::ranges::sort` lead to the underlying context of `std::string` copying during sorting, while `std::swap` just exchanges the pointers in the `std::string`?

See the [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/W8aaj9jnb) with the addresses:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> arr = { "You", "HereIJustWantToHaveMemoryReallocation", "See" };

    std::cout << "\nBefore sorting:";

    for (auto& s : arr) {
        std::cout << "\nString:" << s << " at " << std::addressof(s) << " points to " << (void*)(s.c_str());
    }

    std::sort(arr.begin(), arr.end());

    std::cout << "\nAfter sorting:";
    for (auto& s : arr) {
        std::cout << "\nString:" << s << " at " << std::addressof(s) << " points to " << (void*)(s.c_str());
    }
}
```

The question is not how to avoid this, which can easily be done, for example, with `std::string_view`. The question is, why do `std::sort` and `std::ranges::sort` behave this way?

I would expect the sort algorithm to use `std::swap` or some kind of move semantics which would allow `std::string` to just exchange pointers to the underlying strings, not touching the strings themselves. Why is it not the case?

Comment: Totally unrelated, but why are you printing a leading newline rather than a trailing one (which would make more sense)?

Comment: You're forgetting about SSO. Short strings are not in the heap, they are embedded into the `std::string` objects.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, what is shorter, `\n` or `<< "\n"` when you need to type fast? Why to pay more if there is no difference?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, thank you, just tested on larger strings and it worked. You are right. Somehow I forgot about SSO existence completely.

Comment: Not all systems behave well if the program ends without a newline. And `std::cout` is connected to the C stream `stdout`, which when connected to a terminal is line-buffered. So a leading newline writes the previous line, not the one you're currently printing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the long string it doesn't use small string optimization so the pointer to the string data remains unchanged. In this case, the swap actually just moves the ownership between the two `std::string`s.

For the shorter strings, small string optimization is used and the data pointer is actually a pointer inside the `std::string` object itself. As such, the pointer is unique for each `std::string` and can't be moved to another `std::string`.